# Description after comma belongs to?

Tags: commas, oxford-comma

Let consider below example:

> Varicella Zoster, the virus that causes chickenpox and shingles, a far
>   more dangerous, harmful, and longer-lasting disease in older adults
>   that impacts the nervous system.

I above para which is far more dangerous varicella zoster or shingles?.

Does it mean varicella zoster cause chickenpox and shingles?

Comment: The phrase needs rewriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Varicella-zoster virus (VZV)**" causes chickenpox and herpes zoster (shingles). (http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/231927-overview)

**Varicella zoster virus (VZV**) is one of eight herpesviruses known to infect humans. VZV infections are species-specific to humans. It causes chickenpox (varicella), a disease most commonly affecting children, teens and young adults and herpes zoster (shingles) in older adults; shingles is rare in children.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicella_zoster_virus)

The sentence in question also clearly says about these facts:  "shingles, a far more dangerous, harmful, and longer-lasting disease...."

"Varicella Zoster, the virus that causes chickenpox and shingles,..."

Note: One of the several functions of the punctuation mark 'comma' is to mark off a noun or phrase in Apposition; as,

Milton, the great English poet, was blind.

Varicella Zoster, the virus that causes chickenpox and shingles, impacts
the nervous system.